# How to get logs of all `transfer` methods in blocks?

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereumjs, abi

I want to get logs of all `transfer` methods in the block.

I am using web3.js or ether.js.

I have to set fromBlock and toBlock.

This is my sample code.

But I can't set fromBlock and toBlock.

Now, I get only logs of latest block.

```
web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
                fromBlock: 10150899,
                toBlock: 'latest',
                topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"] // transfer
            }, function(error, result){
                //   if (!error)
                //       console.log(result);
            })
            .on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
                // console.log("subcriptionID === " + subscriptionId);
            })
            .on("data", function(log){
                // console.log(log);
```

How to set fromBlock and toBlock in this sample?

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally have a function to fetch all historical logs. Then have the subscribe function which fetches the latest transactions and you also need a third function that fetches logs that have been missed in case your WebSocket connection drops. (backup)

Answer (score 0):

If this is helpful, I created a video showing how to do this here:

https://youtu.be/VuV-8d2KNQM?t=731

You can take out the filter if you want, but I am using `Alchemy`. You can do this without a provider like Alchemy as well, of course, but this should give you an idea of the setup.